# Me falla consulta dentro de un Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Hago una consulta, para saber el Id de una tabla en especifico cuyo valor los guardo en una variable, esto siempre me da cero y es incorrecto, ya que ese valor se encuentra en esa tabla.

```
set @provi = (select Id From Provincia  Where Nombre = _provincia);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo asi:

```
Select Id Into @provi From Provincia  Where Nombre = _provincia;
```

Comment: gracias lo pude Soluccionar. set @provi := (select Id From Provincia  Where Nombre = _provincia);  Solo le faltaban los dos puntos antes de igual. Eso se hace cuando es una operacion en este caso una consulta. Pero gracias.